# How to install the MariaDB Connector for Python on a Synology NAS

Tags: python, mariadb, synology

On my Synology DS718Plus, I have installed MariaDB 10 and Python3. Both work very well. The database is reachable from external sources and I’ve made several Python programs on my laptop to read/show/write/alter data on several databases on the Synology.

These work fine. However, via SSH, trying to run these Python programs, the installation is missing the mariadb module. Is it possible to install it on a Synology NAS?